# discord.js - music bot is buggy

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

After around 1-2 minutes playin a song my bot says that the playing be finished whatever the songs length is. here is the link to it: https://github.com/Sheesher/amos
i guess this bug aint be caused due to the code...

````
const ytdl = require('ytdl-core-discord');
const validUrl = require('valid-url');

let servers = {};

const play = (msg) => {
  const args = msg.content.substring(1).split(" ");
  const link = args[1];

  if (!link) {
    return msg.channel.send('You must provide a link.');
  };

  if (!msg.member.voice.channel) {
    return msg.channel.send('You have to be in a voice chat.');
  }

  if (!validUrl.isUri(link)) {
    return msg.channel.send('That aint be link.');
  }

  if (!servers[msg.guild.id]) servers[msg.guild.id] = {
    queque: []
  }

  let server = servers[msg.guild.id];
  server.queque.push(link);

  if (!msg.guild.voiceConnection) msg.member.voice.channel.join().then((connection) => {
    playSong(connection, link, msg);
  })
}

const playSong = async (connection, url, msg) => {
  const server = servers[msg.guild.id];
  server.dispatcher = connection.play(await ytdl(url), { type: 'opus' });
  server.queque.shift();
  server.dispatcher.on("end", () => {
    if (server.queque[0]) {
      playSong(connection, url);
    } else {
      connection.disconnect();
    }
  })
  server.dispatcher.on('finish', () => log(s('playing finished')))
}```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually any issue many others suffer from as well. It's because of how YTDL-Core (even the discord version) is handled with the streams on YouTube. If it loses connection then it tries to redirect too it, redirect too much and crash or skips the song. Even the music bot I recently created suffer from this but kept it that way for beginners to learn from it. The way to do this is honestly to just not use YTDL-Core. Use something like lavalink which handles all the music playing for you.